# Error: Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.util.Date

Tags: sql-server, spring, hibernate, date, jquery-ui

I know this has been asked a lot. But I tried all the solutions and still I'm unable to fix the issue.

Entity.java (with getters and setters):

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date projectDate;
```

EntityForm.java (with getters and setters):

```
private Date projectDate;
```

EntityJsp.jspx:

```
<form:input id="project-projectDate" path="entityForm.projectDate" 
class="form-control datepickerDateFuture"/>
```

My table Entity has `projectDate` column data type as `date`.

i tried using `@DateTimeFormat(pattern="MM/dd/yyyy")` on `Entity.java` field. No difference.I am able to save it fine with datatype `String` and `varchar`. I want to save it as `Date`

My environment is: Spring, Hibernate, jquery, SQL Server.

The Error is:

```
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.util.Date for property entityForm.projectDate; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [09/27/2017]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So I figured out the problem. There were other date fields on the page to which I was binding the `DateFormatter` method in my Controller classs.

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.addCustomFormatter(new DateFormatter("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
}
```

To fix it, I had to add another format, specifically for my field.

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.addCustomFormatter(new DateFormatter("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
    binder.addCustomFormatter(new DateFormatter("MM/dd/yyyy","entityForm.projectDate" ));
}
```